# clock source for select()

Tags: sockets, posix

I am investigating the clock sources that common posix objects wait on. I am worried that our code is affected by time changes by user or services like ntp.

It is mostly `CLOCK_REALTIME` or "just the system clock".

E.g:

> The timeout shall be based on the CLOCK_REALTIME clock. The resolution
> of the timeout shall be the resolution of the clock on which it is
> based. The timespec data type is defined in the <time.h> header.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html

This means it is definitely affected by time changes.

I cannot find this information on sockets. There is receive timeout (sockopt `SO_RCVTIMEO`), linger timeout (sockopt `SO_LINGER`) and especially `select()`.
I am particularly interested in `select()` as it can also be called on other file descriptors like mqueues.

Comment: You could use `epoll` instead of `select()`. The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) for `epoll` states that it uses `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: Is the exact duration of the timeout really that important? Note that these functions can also return early when interrupted by a signal.

Comment: @rveerd> thanks, I will look at epoll. And jes the duration is that important. I am on a realtime system here.